# String reference not set to an instance of a String in jmeter create form

Tags: server, jmeter, internal-server-error

I am facing below issues in my script. My scenario is that while I create a form in the application and save the form, it saves easily. But when I try to record the script for the same scenario using firefox or chrome browsers, and click on save button, it shows me an error in the application.
**String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s**

And if I create the script successfully without recording the script and run it, it again shows the same error on save request which is given below. Why it is showing every time? I am not able to create a single form because of this problem. Please help me anyone and take me get out from this.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyNrN.png)

Comment: Could you show us the website and screenshot of  tab "Request"? It looks like the parameter 's' is missing from your request.

Comment: I have checked but there is no missing parameter in the Json file, meanwhile when I try to create a form and save it manually, it works, form saves without any error. but when I try to create and save the from using Jmeter script, it shows me the error.

Comment: Can you show us the request (both header and body)?

Comment: this is the header : Accept */*, Origin http://${path}, X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest, User-Agent Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT6.2;WOW64;rv:21.0)Gecko/20100101Firefox/21.0, Content-Type multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarySeZ3bpEMWQ2qrXVX, Referer http://${path}/u/0/Form/FormList, Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate, Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: in Body data is posting in json format, do you want to see this?

Comment: Yes, please show me the POST , POST data, Cookie Data. (hide your confidential information before post).

Comment: Cookie: RememberUser=; ASP.NET_SessionId=xazsghm5otjk5kbkfuhiy12v it is changing always, managed by cookie manager.

Comment: post data "jsonData"
{"FormCollectionId": "8528","ThemeID": null,"FrmID": "","FormType": "Public Form","FrmName": "formti title556","FormVersionId": "0","FrmDesc": "form description","isNewImage": "false","FrmVer": "Draft","StartDate": "null","EndDate": "null","ValidateAnswersFlag": "false","DeleteAttachmentsOnSyncFlag": "false","IndexPageFlag": "false","StaticMapPath": "","MapImage": "","Barcode": "","IsPublished": "false","Pages": [{"PageID": "0","IsDeletebleItem": "false","FormVersionId": "0","PageName": "Page 1","ItemSet": []},]}
-----------------------------19837128406345--
"

Comment: The StartDate  and EndDate are null. Could you recheck if your application support that?

Comment: I have checked, with or without date there is no issue. Error still remains same

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're testing a .NET-based web application so make sure you:

1. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
2. Detect and handle all dynamic parameteres like [VIEWSTATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx), see [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide for details.

The error you're getting stands for missing or incorrect (not in the string form) parameter, check with the developers what is it and how to properly pass it (maybe it is a custom header or so)

Comment: Yeah, I have added Cookie manager and there is no viewstate parameter, I can successfully login in the application, but Problem is that when I try to create a form and save it manually, it works, form saves without any error. but when I try to create and save the from using Jmeter script, it shows me that error. is there any reason behind this?

Comment: Application is on MVC structure so there is no viewstate.